# Connection reset error(server/client) -Using the class ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a connection between a server and multiple clients, but it doesn't work even for one.  All I want to do is to send from the client an object using the `ObjectOutputStream` class. The connection is made successfully at the beginning but when I try to send the object to the server it fails.

This is the client part which is written in the main method of a class:

```
              Socket socket;
              OutputStream out;
              ObjectOutputStream fout;
              boolean connected=false;

              if (!connected) {
                    try {
                        socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);
                        out = socket.getOutputStream();
                        fout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
                        fout.flush();
                        connected = true;
                        fout.writeObject(ac1);//ac is an object of Plane class
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.toString());

                    }
                }
```

This is the server:

```
public class server {
static class ServerThread implements Runnable {
    Socket client = null;

    public ServerThread(Socket c) {
        this.client = c;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
           System.out.println("Connected to client : "+client.getInetAddress().getHostName());
           Plane ac=null;
           InputStream in=client.getInputStream();
           ObjectInputStream fin=new ObjectInputStream(in);
            while(client.isConnected()){
                ac = (Plane)fin.readObject();
                System.out.println(ac.toString());

            }
            client.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8000);
            while (true) {
                Socket p = server.accept();
                new Thread(new ServerThread(p)).start();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client never closes the socket, and presumably exits, so the connection is reset. So close the socket.

NB `isConnected()` is not a valid loop condition. It will never become false. Your loop should terminate when `EOFExceprion` is caught.